# How to insert data to multiple table at once in hibernate using java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi I am using hibernate to save data into two tables on a database .Also, I am using mysql .

These are my POJO classes,

**Patient.java**

```
public class Patient implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idPatient;
private String title;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private Date dob;
private Boolean martitalStatus;
private String gender;
private String nic;
private Date dateCreated;
private Date lastUpdated;
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0);

public Patient() {
}

public Patient(Date lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}

public Patient(String title, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, Date dob, Boolean martitalStatus, String gender, String nic, Date dateCreated, Date lastUpdated, Set<Contact> contacts) {
    this.title = title;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.martitalStatus = martitalStatus;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.nic = nic;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public Integer getIdPatient() {
    return this.idPatient;
}

public void setIdPatient(Integer idPatient) {
    this.idPatient = idPatient;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return this.middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public Date getDob() {
    return this.dob;
}

public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public Boolean getMartitalStatus() {
    return this.martitalStatus;
}

public void setMartitalStatus(Boolean martitalStatus) {
    this.martitalStatus = martitalStatus;
}

public String getGender() {
    return this.gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getNic() {
    return this.nic;
}

public void setNic(String nic) {
    this.nic = nic;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

public Date getLastUpdated() {
    return this.lastUpdated;
}

public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}

public Set<Contact> getContacts() {
    return this.contacts;
}

public void setContacts(Set<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer idContact;
 private Patient patient;
 private String telephone;
 private String address;

public Contact() {
}


public Contact(Patient patient) {
    this.patient = patient;
}
public Contact(Patient patient, String telephone, String address) {
   this.patient = patient;
   this.telephone = telephone;
   this.address = address;
}

public Integer getIdContact() {
    return this.idContact;
}

public void setIdContact(Integer idContact) {
    this.idContact = idContact;
}
public Patient getPatient() {
    return this.patient;
}

public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
    this.patient = patient;
}
public String getTelephone() {
    return this.telephone;
}

public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Also I am not using annotations in here.

```
    Patient patient=new Patient();
    Contact contact=new Contact();

    Set<Contact> contacts=new HashSet<Contact>();
    contact.setTelephone("0358965458");
    contact.setAddress("Horana");        
    contacts.add(contact);

    patient.setFirstName("Wajira");
    patient.setLastName("Dahanushka");
    patient.setDateCreated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());
    patient.setLastUpdated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());        
    patient.setGender("Male");
    patient.setTitle("Mr");
    patient.setNic("9115580466v");
    patient.setContacts(contacts);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory=new HibernateUtil().getSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();     
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.persist(patient);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

**Patient.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 8, 2016 9:56:01 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="db.Patient" table="patient" catalog="example_hibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idPatient" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idPatient" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="title" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="firstName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="lastName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="middleName" type="string">
            <column name="middleName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="dob" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="martitalStatus" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="martitalStatus" />
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="nic" type="string">
            <column name="nic" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="dateCreated" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="lastUpdated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="contacts" table="contact" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="idPatient" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="db.Contact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Contact.hbm.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 8, 2016 9:56:01 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="db.Contact" table="contact" catalog="example_hibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idContact" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idContact" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="patient" class="db.Patient" fetch="select">
            <column name="idPatient" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="telephone" type="string">
            <column name="telephone" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="string">
            <column name="address" length="45" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Contact table has a foreign key which is the primary key of the patient table.

When I run above code , A new patient record could see in patient table but couldn't see any new contact record in contact table .

Is there anything wrong.
Have any ideas .

Comment: Where you define the hibernate mapping? Can you Show it please

Comment: My guess is that, as you have defined it, a `Patient` is not the owning side of the relationship with contacts.  Therefore, persisting a `Patient` does not persist its contacts.

Comment: Whether using annotations or XML to define your entity relationships, you will need to specify a OneToMany relationship between your Patient and Contact classes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : So what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **Patient.hbm.xml**
while mentioning the `set` for contacts, use the following cascade property

```
<set name="contacts" table="contact" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="idPatient" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="db.Contact" />
        </set>
```

By mentioning cascade as `save-update`, you just have to invoke `session.save(patientObj)`, and contact details will automatically get persisted.

Check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) link for complete reference of cascading updates/inserts/delete operation in hibernate associations.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Hibernate that you have a one to many relationship betweens patients and their contacts.  After you have done this, persisting a `Patient` object should also persist the entire graph of that patient.  If you were using annotations, then something like this should work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Patient")
public class Patient {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="patient")
    private Set<Contact>  contacts;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class Contact {
    @ManyToOne
    private Patient patient;
}
```

Comment: I want to set one to one relationship . And I am not using annotations  in there .

Comment: If you want a one-to-one relationship, then why are you using a collection of contacts for each patient?

Comment: It has been generated by hibernate reverse engineering wizard in netbeans.

Comment: Update your question and show us your config files.

Comment: I have added my config files.